# AlertDialog crash on orientation change

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, orientation-changes

There are so many threads on this topic and all their suggestions do not solve the problem. This situation is more complicated as a background service is feeding data that is graphed into an AlertDialog. The service uses the LocalBroadcastManager to pass an Intent to the main activity which contains the onCreateDialog callback. The data is coming quite quickly.

I have tried calling removeDialog in the onPause(), setting the context to null so the thread wont call it while null,  and in the onStart I pass the new context to the thread that signals the Broadcast Receiver. Log messages show the removal of the dialogs getting called. After the screen orientation has been changed the showDialog() method now triggers the onCreateDialog() callback. When that callback is signaled, the findViewById() returns null as expected since the dialogs have been removed (supposidly) but I still get that dreaded error

"**java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**"

(How to call 'removeView' on an AlertDialog is also something I cannot not find an answer to and no one else in this forum has found an answer to that either!)

The only thing I can think of is that Broadcast events are queued that have the wrong context. Perhaps there is a way to clear all Intents heading to the Broadcast receiver?

Here is the code for the onCreateDialog. The graphic view is in 'waveForm.get(id)'. It does work nicely and display the graphs (not continuously as I would like) but then upon orientation change it's death!

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Alert Dialog 'onCreateDialog' method has been called with id " + id);
    if(this.findViewById(id) != null)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Alert Dialog view exists!");
        return null;
    }

    switch(id)
    {
        case 0:
        Builder bldr = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        Dialog alert = bldr.setView(waveForm.get(id)).setNegativeButton("Dismiss " + id, 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    } 
                }).create();

        alert.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, waveForm.get(id).getCurrentHeight());
        return alert;

        case 1:
        Builder bldr1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        Dialog alert1 = bldr1.setView(waveForm.get(id)).setNegativeButton("Dismiss " + id, 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    } 
                }).create();

        alert1.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, waveForm.get(id).getCurrentHeight());
        return alert1;

        case 2:
        Builder bldr2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        Dialog alert2 = bldr2.setView(waveForm.get(id)).setNegativeButton("Dismiss " + id, 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    } 
                }).create();

        alert2.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, waveForm.get(id).getCurrentHeight());
        return alert2;

    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your code? it is probably a View you are attaching to the Dialog and not the Dialog itself. Make sure not to add a View to your Dialog before removing it - if being attached - from its current parent.

Comment: I added the onCreateDialog code. It does work until I change screen orientation so the view must be getting attached. I even get all three dialogs up and running but one on top of another.